# Pebble: What does the onlyShownOnCommunication in appinfo.json metadata do?

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

In CloudPebble, there is a setting for App Visibility:

[image]

What does "Only Visible When Companion App Running" mean exactly? Does it mean when the iOS/Android companion app isn't running, then the Pebble watchapp doesn't show up in the app list on the Pebble?

I tried to look for information on the App Metadata docs page, https://developer.pebble.com/guides/pebble-apps/app-structure/app-metadata/, but it's broken...

I tried the setting on a watchapp I have that has an iOS companion app, and the setting doesn't seem to do anything at all. When I forcequit my iOS app, the watchapp is still listed in the Pebble app list.

Comment: For me it seems to take a while (a bit too long IMO) for the menu item to disappear after closing the companion app (just configuration in this case). Tested on Android.

Answer (score 0):

This metadata item causes the watch app to be hidden when the phone app can't communicated with the watch, and to be shown when it can. The reason it stays open is because apps that use the new PebbleKit on iOS are allowed to continue communicating over BLE, [even when force closed](https://developer.pebble.com/guides/communication/using-pebblekit-ios/#bluetooth-low-energy-ble-connections).